# Use fetch to post a blob in react-native

Tags: android, blob, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to post a blob. It's definitely a blob. This isn't working in react-native though. I'm getting a red screen that says "PUT must have a request body". Well, I've put the blob in the request body.

```
createAttachment: function(url, blob) {
  var settings = {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'image/jpeg',
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
      'If-Match': '*',
    },
    body: blob
  };
  return fetch(url, settings)
}
```

Comment: You sure you don't mean POST and not PUT?

Comment: either way I get the same error "POST must have a request body"

Comment: actually POST gives a different error: "Exception creating JSON string: null"

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/854) it seems like fetched blob data doesn't get marshaled or mapped to js memory across the bridge like strings are. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Does anyone have a working example?  I'm struggling even to create the Blob object.

Answer (score 11):

My project had same problem before, according to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/854) perhaps, blob data is not supported in react native `fetch` API currently (Both in send and receive).

So I made a module myself ..

https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob

It works fine in our project, if you don't mind to take a look, it might helps.

Comment: omg you're the creator of fetch-blob? i need your help!!! please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050839/how-to-send-multiple-data-at-once-using-fetch-blob-react-native

Answer (score 0):

Use `rn-fetch-blob` lib for this:
https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#user-content-upload-example--dropbox-files-upload-api

Comment: How I will create a blob from binary data using this package?

Comment: @Tarun Method in link just takes base64 and sends it via http. You can google how to convert your data to appropriate format using js tools